# nth order differential equation into n first order simultaneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I was studying state equations by Norman s.and in his book it is written that "an nth order differential equation can be converted to n simultaneous first order differential equation",

so anyone can tell how it can be proved rigrously ?

Comment: Perhaps they're referring to this idea: if you start, for example, with $y''' + xy'' + 17y' = x^5$, you can set $y_0=y$, $y_1=y'$, and $y_2=y''$ and obtain the system \begin{align*} y_0' &= y_1 \\ y_1' &= y_2 \\ y_2' + xy_2 + 17y_1 &= x^5.\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Given $c_n z^{(n)} + c_{n-1} z^{(n-1)} + \dots + c_{1}z^{(1)} + c_{0}z = 0$ where $z^{(q)} = \frac{d^q z}{d t^{q}}$ denotes the $q$ derivative with respect to time, let
\begin{align}
x := \begin{bmatrix} 
z \\
z^{(1)}\\
z^{(2)} \\
\vdots \\
z^{(n-1)}
\end{bmatrix} \qquad x^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix} 
z^{(1)} \\
z^{(2)}\\
z^{(3)} \\
\vdots \\
z^{(n)}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Then we can represent $c_n z^{(n)} + c_{n-1} z^{(n-1)} + \dots + c_{1}z^{(1)} + c_{0}z = 0$ as the ODE,
\begin{align}
x^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\
 \vdots & & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\
 \frac{-c_{0}}{c_{n}} & \frac{-c_{1}}{c_{n}} & \frac{-c_{2}}{c_{n}} & \frac{-c_{3}}{c_{n}} & \cdots & \frac{-c_{n-1}}{c_{n}}
\end{bmatrix} x
\end{align}